# What does the objective of the primal tell us about the dual?

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

So lets say the primal of the problem is written like this:

$$\max \sum^n_{j=1}c_jx_j$$
$$\text{subject to } \sum^n_{j=1}a_{ij}x_j\le b_i\qquad i=1,2,\ldots,m$$

$$\qquad x_j\ge 0\qquad j=1,2,\ldots,n$$

If the objective function (c) is negative, what does that mean for the dual?

Comment: can you show us your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dual constraints are $\sum_i a_{ij} y_i \ge c_j,$ so $c_j < 0$ implies that the constant zero solution $y\equiv 0$ is dual feasible.

Comment: So the dual will always be feasible? Can it no be unbounded? Or does feasible include unboundedness?

Comment: In general, feasible includes the possibility of unboundedness,

Comment: Ohh, I see! But I still find it a bit weird that the dual is always feasible. What if the primal has negative entries in the objective function, put the constraints make it unbounded, wont the dual be infeasible then?

Comment: $\sum_i a_{ij} \cdot 0 = 0 \ge c_{ij}$, so $0$ is dual feasible.  The primal cannot be unbounded here because the primal objective function to be maximized is $\sum_j c_j x_j \le 0$ since $c_j < 0$ and $x_{ij} \ge 0$.

Comment: Okay, my bad! Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I meant $x_j \ge 0$.

Comment: @ RobPratt. I was looking at the question again, and was wondering. What if the primal with negative entries in c is infeasible, does that not mean that dual can be infeasible?

Comment: The feasibility/infeasibility of the primal does not change the fact that $y \equiv 0$ is dual feasible,